# Difference between --ask-pass and --ask-sudo-pass in ansible?

Tags: ansible, devops, ansible-inventory

I am was trying to write some ansible playbooks and got confused with *ask_pass* and *ask_sudo_pass*. Can anyone give me a clear idea on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an inventory one provides the connection to a host, e.g.

```
[local_test]
test-host ansible_ssh_user=some_user ansible_host=192.168.0.2
```

Note that no password or key is given in the inventory. One could provide the password of that user on the CLI by providing the argument in the command, e.g; `ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i inventory ask_pass`. Reason to not place the password in the inventory is when using shared files, e.g. when placing the inventory in Git.

Now, `ask_sudo_pass` is meant when sudo privileges are required, e.g:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: True # Execute whole playbook with root privileges
  tasks:
    - shell: whoami
      register: me

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ me.stdout }}"
```

Output:

```
TASK [debug] *
  ok: [localhost] => 
    msg: root
```

TLDR: One is for asking a password for the user, the other one is asking for the password for admin privileges